# Have only one breakpoint in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So we have a variable-column number table based on user-defined number of items chosen for a comparison.  I have the following specified:

```js
responsive: {
                     details: {
                         display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
                         type: 'column'
                     }
```

The effect I get is that each column shrinks to a certain minimum level, after which the rightmost column disappears and the content gets pushed to a second row that shows immediately under the subsequent ones with a bullet that represents the column that just disappeared.  Shrinking the screen futher causes additional columns to disappear in the same manner with additional bullets representing them.

What I want to do is only have one breakpoint so to speak, so that at a certain critical width (ie, the one at which the first (rightmost) column would disappear), ALL the columns would then be pushed to that bulleted list.  The problem with the way it works currently is that it's not very intuitive to have, for example, 3 columns with column header, and another row underneath that with just one spanned column and a bullet (or a few bullets).  So my thought is either display it as a bulleted list, or a set of columns with headers, but not a combination, since that could be pretty confusing.

However, when I try specifying custom breakpoints as in:

```js
breakpoints: [
   { name: 'desktop', width: Infinity },
   { name: 'phone',   width: 480 }
  ]
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect.  Just wondering if this sort of thing is possible and if so hot to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the plugin for a while, I determined that at least one way to do this is to specify a class for each header that tells the plugin a minimum with with which to display it as a column (and otherwise displaying it either as a bullet underneath, not displaying it at all, etc, depending on other options selected.  There are built in breakpoints and logical prefixes that you can use for the classes of a given column header -eg "min-destkop" or "min-tablet-p" (for tablet in portrait mode) with specific predefined pixel widths.  However you can also define custom ones via the breakpoints object.  It's a little tricky though. I found I had to define all of them and set my breakpoint to min of the one after my breakpoint:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content_0_main_1_GridView1  th:nth-child(1)').addClass("min-tablet-l");
        $('#content_0_main_1_GridView1  th:nth-child(2)').addClass("min-tablet-l");
        $('#content_0_main_1_GridView1  th:nth-child(3)').addClass("min-tablet-l");
        $('#content_0_main_1_GridView1  th:nth-child(4)').addClass("min-tablet-l")
             $('#content_0_main_1_GridView1').DataTable({
                 searching: false,
                
                 bPaginate: false,
                 ordering: false,
                 
                
                 autoWidth: false,
                 responsive: {
                     breakpoints: [
           
                     { name: 'desktop', width: Infinity },
                            { name: 'tablet-l', width: 1024 },
                            { name: 'tablet-p', width: 623 },
                            { name: 'mobile-l', width: 480 },
                            { name: 'mobile-p', width: 320 }
           
                     ],
                     details: {
                         display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
                         type: 'column'
                     }
                 }
                 
             });
         });
```

Basically, I'm manually changing the classes of these column headers with jquery because they are being autogenerated via a C# gridview. My goal was to have it break at 640px since a different unrelated table on the same page was breaking at that point.  In order to do this I needed to set the tablet-p with 640 and have the class for breaking set to the min of the breakpoint one bigger than that.  Maybe there was an easier, more straightforward way, but this worked.  Well, it worked mostly.  Turns out, maybe due to padding, not sure exactly, that it was actually breaking at 657 or so, so I had to tweak the tablet-p value a bit to get it to ACTUALLY break at 640px...